# Compile Error when using different VBA codes in same window

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I have a number of things I want to achieve using VBA on a particular sheet.

1) Have a 3 button message box pop up when a certain condition is met.

2) Display the active cell address in a specific cell.

3) When hitting Enter after inputting data only to empty cells in a particular column, make the cursor jump to another column on the same row.

(Codes for each of these are at the end of the post)

I have the code to do all three of these things and they all work fine on their own, indeed the codes for items 1 & 2 also both work fine together, but when I add the code for item 3, a message box appears with 
"Compile Error: 
Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_SelectionChange"
and the offending article in the code window is also highlighted.

I've noticed that the code for items 2 & 3 have the heading "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)"

If I remove the code for item 2, im then faced with a different message box 
"Compile Error: Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property"
and highlights the words "Option Explicit" in the code window. 
This also seems to break the code for item 1 as well.

I suspect the fact that I have two sets of code in the same window with the same "heading" might be the issue here. Is there a way for me to "blend" them so that they'll all play nicely with each other?

```
**---CODE FOR ITEM 1---**

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Range("L:L")
    If r.Value < 0 Then
result = MsgBox("You do not have enough stock to fulfil this request" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Please click: -" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "    -Abort to order more stock" & vbNewLine & _
    "    -Retry to enter a different value" & vbNewLine & _
    "    -Ignore to receive stock", _
 _
vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbDefaultButton2 + vbExclamation, "Negative Stock Level Warning")
End If
Next r

If result = vbAbort Then
MsgBox "Opening web browser", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "New program warning!"
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink _
      Address:="https://uk.rs-online.com/login", _
      NewWindow:=True
End If

If result = vbRetry Then
MsgBox "Please enter a smaller parts count value", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Parts Count Input"
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
End If


If result = vbIgnore Then
MsgBox "You will now be directed to the Goods In window", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Receive Stock"
Sheets("Goods In").Activate
End If

End Sub
```

**---CODE FOR ITEM 2---**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Range("A1048575") = ActiveCell.Address

End Sub
```

**---CODE FOR ITEM 3---**

```
   Option Explicit

    Dim emptyCell As Boolean

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub ' don't bother with multicell selections
        If Cells(1, Target.Column).Value <> "S.I.#" Then Exit Sub ' don't bother with selections outside "S.I.#" column
        If emptyCell And Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then Cells(Target.Row, Range("A1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Find(what:="Count", _
        LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column).Select ' if current cell was empty and now it is not then skip to "Count" column same row
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        emptyCell = IsEmpty(Target.Value) ' store the info about current selection being empty
    End Sub
```

Comment: There should only be `Option Explicit` at the top of the module... and you can only have one `Worksheet_SelectionChange` handler.

Comment: Read this: https://trumpexcel.com/vba-events/

Comment: ok I have moved the code
{Range("A1048575") = ActiveCell.Address}
to "ThisWorkbook" in the VBA module so it no longer interferes with the rest of the code and the code for item 3 now behaves correctly.

I now have another bit of code:
{Set h = Range("K:K")
If Intersect(Target, h) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Cells(Target.Row + 1, "E").Select
ActiveCell.ClearContents}
so when I press Enter in column K, I go to the next row in column E

Both of these work separately, but I can't work out how to make them both work. Do I need to put one of them on a "new Module" and make it sheet specific?

Comment: Can see some problems in your `Worksheet.Calculate` code - you're checking every cell in column L even if only the first row has data.  Your code is only acting on the result of the last message it gives on the last row of column L - if L1<0 it will display the message, but won't do anything with the answer; the only cell it will work on is L1048576.